# Convert .csv with polygon geometry to .shp QGIS

Tags: shapefile, polygon, qgis-2, csv

Working on a Mac in QGI 2.12, I have a csv file with polygon geometry coordinates that I would like to save to a shapefile. It displays fine as a csv. However, when I try to use "save as," I get the following error message:

> Export to vector file failed.
>   Error: creation of layer failed (OGR error:Geometry type of `Unrecognised: 1006' not supported in shapefiles.
>   Type can be overridden with a layer creation option
>   of SHPT=POINT/ARC/POLYGON/MULTIPOINT/POINTZ/ARCZ/POLYGONZ/MULTIPOINTZ.)

The suggested overwrite doesn't work, nor have I found anything online. Perhaps it's my formatting in the csv file? In the original file, the polygon coordinates are saved in WKT format (I believe):

> MULTIPOLYGON (((29.1753 -2.255635 0,29.175036 -2.255789 0,29.174466 -2.255756 0,29.174251 -2.255491 0,29.174126 -2.255336 0,29.174137 -2.255071 0,29.1744 -2.254762 0,29.174466 -2.254442 0,29.174412 -2.254111 0,29.17439 -2.253647 0,29.174895 -2.253449 0,29.175509 -2.253294 0,29.175784 -2.253339 0,29.176047 -2.25356 0,29.176091 -2.253858 0,29.176047 -2.2542 0,29.175926 -2.254476 0,29.175596 -2.255127 0,29.1753 -2.255635 0)),((29.164197 -2.259666 0,29.163793 -2.259877 0,29.163325 -2.259795 0,29.162905 -2.259454 0,29.162695 -2.258511 0,29.161969 -2.25799 0,29.16163 -2.257275 0,29.161275 -2.257129 0,29.160774 -2.256836 0,29.160694 -2.256169 0,29.160516 -2.255747 0,29.160466 -2.255575 0,29.160339 -2.255145 0,29.160434 -2.254874 0,29.160533 -2.254593 0,29.160872 -2.254398 0,29.161354 -2.254261 0,29.161858 -2.254025 0,29.162246 -2.254058 0,29.162633 -2.254448 0,29.162681 -2.254984 0,29.162623 -2.255225 0,29.162503 -2.255715 0,29.162713 -2.256171 0,29.163117 -2.256398 0,29.163763 -2.256529 0,29.163973 -2.256984 0,29.163924 -2.25752 0,29.163988 -2.258089 0,29.164121 -2.258596 0,29.164214 -2.25895 0,29.164197 -2.259666 0)),((29.183875 -2.261869 0,29.183398 -2.262193 0,29.183199 -2.262085 0,29.183438 -2.261398 0,29.183522 -2.261158 0,29.183777 -2.261237 0,29.183921 -2.261281 0,29.184059 -2.261498 0,29.183875 -2.261869 0)),((29.152402 -2.266796 0,29.152302 -2.266825 0,29.15216 -2.26676 0,29.152082 -2.266467 0,29.152495 -2.265838 0,29.152652 -2.265551 0,29.152652 -2.265115 0,29.152652 -2.264929 0,29.15288 -2.2647 0,29.153512 -2.264701 0,29.153505 -2.264915 0,29.15337 -2.26527 0,29.153164 -2.265459 0,29.153028 -2.265967 0,29.152736 -2.266389 0,29.152402 -2.266796 0)),((29.136693 -2.269719 0,29.13624 -2.270309 0,29.135436 -2.269785 0,29.135319 -2.269465 0,29.136023 -2.268673 0,29.136376 -2.268251 0,29.137096 -2.268235 0,29.137683 -2.267831 0,29.137884 -2.267561 0,29.138572 -2.267595 0,29.13837 -2.267781 0,29.13775 -2.268084 0,29.137465 -2.268286 0,29.137264 -2.268539 0,29.137247 -2.268741 0,29.137146 -2.268994 0,29.136978 -2.269314 0,29.136693 -2.269719 0)),((29.146501 -2.272407 0,29.146197 -2.272447 0,29.146054 -2.272238 0,29.14607 -2.271893 0,29.146159 -2.271636 0,29.146342 -2.271403 0,29.146717 -2.271395 0,29.14694 -2.271548 0,29.14702 -2.271789 0,29.146892 -2.27199 0,29.1467 -2.272126 0,29.146501 -2.272407 0)),((29.146555 -2.274471 0,29.146985 -2.274616 0,29.147372 -2.274515 0,29.147644 -2.274314 0,29.14779 -2.274455 0,29.147909 -2.274532 0,29.148016 -2.274602 0,29.148088 -2.274933 0,29.148073 -2.27525 0,29.147901 -2.275574 0,29.147772 -2.275755 0,29.1475 -2.276057 0,29.147393 -2.276182 0,29.147156 -2.27646 0,29.146626 -2.276763 0,29.146196 -2.27718 0,29.145666 -2.277598 0,29.145508 -2.278131 0,29.145579 -2.27865 0,29.145779 -2.27914 0,29.146152 -2.279169 0,29.14667 -2.27858 0,29.146911 -2.278045 0,29.147255 -2.277916 0,29.147527 -2.278103 0,29.147613 -2.278507 0,29.147727 -2.278925 0,29.147763 -2.279335 0,29.147533 -2.279739 0,29.14749 -2.2802 0,29.147748 -2.280517 0,29.148149 -2.280676 0,29.148364 -2.280849 0,29.148451 -2.280949 0,29.148678 -2.281209 0,29.149079 -2.281339 0,29.149215 -2.281548 0,29.149144 -2.281822 0,29.148843 -2.282196 0,29.148828 -2.282629 0,29.148699 -2.282787 0,29.148495 -2.282921 0,29.147997 -2.283248 0,29.147954 -2.283637 0,29.148376 -2.283861 0,29.14892 -2.284019 0,29.149723 -2.283833 0,29.150009 -2.283919 0,29.14998 -2.284179 0,29.14965 -2.284539 0,29.149462 -2.284785 0,29.149364 -2.284913 0,29.149235 -2.285129 0,29.149292 -2.285403 0,29.149378 -2.28572 0,29.14932 -2.285994 0,29.149191 -2.286224 0,29.149012 -2.286433 0,29.148468 -2.286505 0,29.148281 -2.286735 0,29.14831 -2.28698 0,29.148295 -2.287168 0,29.147708 -2.287038 0,29.147435 -2.287057 0,29.147307 -2.287066 0,29.147021 -2.287253 0,29.146848 -2.28757 0,29.14678 -2.287751 0,29.146648 -2.288103 0,29.146547 -2.288334 0,29.146046 -2.288636 0,29.145931 -2.289025 0,29.145981 -2.289421 0,29.145723 -2.289709 0,29.145594 -2.290156 0,29.145765 -2.290401 0,29.146266 -2.290805 0,29.146395 -2.291064 0,29.14661 -2.291598 0,29.147068 -2.291828 0,29.147404 -2.292066 0,29.147404 -2.292383 0,29.147361 -2.292628 0,29.147175 -2.292671 0,29.146745 -2.292541 0,29.14643 -2.292354 0,29.146123 -2.292083 0,29.145972 -2.29195 0,29.145809 -2.291832 0,29.145514 -2.291619 0,29.145142 -2.291345 0,29.144684 -2.291186 0,29.143838 -2.2912 0,29.143781 -2.290998 0,29.143925 -2.290753 0,29.143953 -2.290465 0,29.143739 -2.289888 0,29.143567 -2.289398 0,29.143353 -2.28924 0,29.142994 -2.289383 0,29.142765 -2.289355 0,29.142522 -2.289066 0,29.142608 -2.288519 0,29.142775 -2.288236 0,29.142838 -2.28813 0,29.14311 -2.28777 0,29.143153 -2.287481 0,29.143153 -2.287208 0,29.142738 -2.286761 0,29.142767 -2.286314 0,29.143469 -2.286127 0,29.144207 -2.286221 0,29.144278 -2.285976 0,29.14434 -2.285655 0,29.144365 -2.28553 0,29.144409 -2.28532 0,29.144471 -2.285022 0,29.144193 -2.284694 0,29.143792 -2.284679 0,29.143205 -2.284837 0,29.14268 -2.28499 0,29.14256 -2.285024 0,29.142059 -2.284981 0,29.14183 -2.284635 0,29.141837 -2.284401 0,29.141844 -2.284174 0,29.14226 -2.283742 0,29.142962 -2.283742 0,29.143965 -2.283642 0,29.144459 -2.283433 0,29.144688 -2.283001 0,29.144732 -2.282569 0,29.144517 -2.282252 0,29.144235 -2.282024 0,29.143944 -2.28179 0,29.143543 -2.281386 0,29.143615 -2.281141 0,29.144156 -2.280875 0,29.144289 -2.28081 0,29.144654 -2.280616 0,29.144711 -2.2804 0,29.144482 -2.28014 0,29.144368 -2.279809 0,29.144433 -2.279384 0,29.144232 -2.278822 0,29.14439 -2.278447 0,29.144544 -2.278284 0,29.144634 -2.278188 0,29.1448 -2.278094 0,29.144963 -2.278001 0,29.145064 -2.277684 0,29.14515 -2.277453 0,29.145216 -2.277329 0,29.145408 -2.276964 0,29.145351 -2.276488 0,29.145208 -2.276027 0,29.14528 -2.275566 0,29.145065 -2.275119 0,29.144923 -2.274514 0,29.144972 -2.274176 0,29.145038 -2.273736 0,29.145191 -2.273491 0,29.145281 -2.273347 0,29.145511 -2.273188 0,29.145783 -2.273246 0,29.145979 -2.273445 0,29.146155 -2.273967 0,29.146312 -2.274298 0,29.146555 -2.274471 0)),((29.139323 -2.281881 0,29.139454 -2.28232 0,29.139323 -2.28254 0,29.139117 -2.282694 0,29.138973 -2.282825 0,29.138667 -2.282979 0,29.138405 -2.28333 0,29.138029 -2.283472 0,29.137881 -2.283528 0,29.137466 -2.283506 0,29.137309 -2.283315 0,29.137051 -2.283 0,29.13674 -2.28249 0,29.136505 -2.282304 0,29.136244 -2.282099 0,29.135829 -2.282055 0,29.135414 -2.282164 0,29.134409 -2.282493 0,29.133929 -2.281988 0,29.133864 -2.281548 0,29.13393 -2.280867 0,29.133821 -2.280406 0,29.134149 -2.280032 0,29.134545 -2.279811 0,29.134738 -2.279703 0,29.135328 -2.279856 0,29.135503 -2.279901 0,29.135874 -2.280099 0,29.136752 -2.280511 0,29.136967 -2.280646 0,29.137183 -2.280781 0,29.137642 -2.281045 0,29.137944 -2.281165 0,29.138302 -2.281308 0,29.138472 -2.281375 0,29.138733 -2.28153 0,29.139045 -2.281716 0,29.139323 -2.281881 0)),((29.186365 -2.260417 0,29.186795 -2.260077 0,29.186881 -2.25974 0,29.187511 -2.259952 0,29.187886 -2.260078 0,29.188455 -2.260279 0,29.188854 -2.260388 0,29.1895 -2.260465 0,29.189822 -2.260651 0,29.190436 -2.261332 0,29.190451 -2.261965 0,29.190613 -2.262375 0,29.190889 -2.262947 0,29.190963 -2.263368 0,29.191134 -2.264339 0,29.191984 -2.265173 0,29.192294 -2.265476 0,29.192432 -2.265723 0,29.193123 -2.266435 0,29.19343 -2.266775 0,29.19366 -2.26727 0,29.19352 -2.268438 0,29.193467 -2.268947 0,29.193344 -2.269179 0,29.192791 -2.269596 0,29.191899 -2.269951 0,29.191169 -2.270747 0,29.191506 -2.272246 0,29.191936 -2.273313 0,29.192175 -2.27409 0,29.192303 -2.274506 0,29.192383 -2.275106 0,29.192462 -2.275375 0,29.192502 -2.275537 0,29.192502 -2.275699 0,29.192563 -2.275882 0,29.192709 -2.276008 0,29.192845 -2.276126 0,29.193127 -2.276268 0,29.193248 -2.27643 0,29.19345 -2.276653 0,29.193631 -2.276836 0,29.193954 -2.276917 0,29.194216 -2.276938 0,29.194498 -2.276979 0,29.19474 -2.277121 0,29.194842 -2.277441 0,29.194793 -2.277518 0,29.194676 -2.2777 0,29.194616 -2.278079 0,29.194343 -2.278626 0,29.194026 -2.279447 0,29.193784 -2.279872 0,29.193338 -2.280199 0,29.193066 -2.281034 0,29.192899 -2.281703 0,29.192763 -2.282174 0,29.192642 -2.282721 0,29.192339 -2.283435 0,29.192014 -2.2844 0,29.191757 -2.28484 0,29.191636 -2.285007 0,29.191666 -2.285539 0,29.191756 -2.286178 0,29.192088 -2.286877 0,29.192284 -2.287257 0,29.192284 -2.28788 0,29.192321 -2.288526 0,29.192397 -2.288784 0,29.192532 -2.28924 0,29.192653 -2.289544 0,29.192743 -2.289939 0,29.192607 -2.290274 0,29.192562 -2.290471 0,29.192547 -2.290851 0,29.19238 -2.291216 0,29.191821 -2.291565 0,29.191292 -2.29158 0,29.190567 -2.291595 0,29.189963 -2.29129 0,29.189329 -2.29091 0,29.188876 -2.290575 0,29.188393 -2.290514 0,29.187607 -2.290575 0,29.187048 -2.290635 0,29.18669 -2.290698 0,29.186106 -2.29055 0,29.185507 -2.290502 0,29.185334 -2.290833 0,29.185263 -2.291136 0,29.184823 -2.291789 0,29.184627 -2.291802 0,29.184419 -2.291416 0,29.183981 -2.290143 0,29.18356 -2.289383 0,29.182753 -2.288517 0,29.182455 -2.28774 0,29.181897 -2.286845 0,29.181488 -2.286879 0,29.180956 -2.286924 0,29.180084 -2.286463 0,29.179498 -2.285801 0,29.179413 -2.285602 0,29.179155 -2.284995 0,29.178983 -2.285067 0,29.178812 -2.285369 0,29.178754 -2.285858 0,29.178673 -2.286209 0,29.178582 -2.286606 0,29.178498 -2.286882 0,29.178381 -2.287268 0,29.178166 -2.287958 0,29.178023 -2.288591 0,29.17792 -2.289232 0,29.177754 -2.289616 0,29.177555 -2.29015 0,29.177057 -2.290917 0,29.176759 -2.291284 0,29.176452 -2.291275 0,29.175955 -2.290507 0,29.175225 -2.29029 0,29.174147 -2.290339 0,29.173749 -2.290506 0,29.173351 -2.290756 0,29.172853 -2.291089 0,29.17214 -2.29169 0,29.171792 -2.29189 0,29.171253 -2.291948 0,29.170755 -2.291931 0,29.170486 -2.291883 0,29.170192 -2.29183 0,29.169727 -2.29193 0,29.169547 -2.292017 0,29.169279 -2.292147 0,29.168933 -2.292232 0,29.168792 -2.292419 0,29.168741 -2.292635 0,29.168466 -2.292847 0,29.167936 -2.293097 0,29.167732 -2.29324 0,29.167661 -2.293291 0,29.167433 -2.293451 0,29.166973 -2.293775 0,29.166844 -2.293865 0,29.166658 -2.293997 0,29.166037 -2.29252 0,29.166054 -2.291736 0,29.166486 -2.291069 0,29.166714 -2.290816 0,29.167533 -2.289549 0,29.167942 -2.288916 0,29.168352 -2.288283 0,29.168761 -2.287649 0,29.16917 -2.287016 0,29.16958 -2.286383 0,29.169989 -2.285749 0,29.170399 -2.285116 0,29.170808 -2.284483 0,29.171217 -2.28385 0,29.171627 -2.283216 0,29.172036 -2.282583 0,29.172446 -2.28195 0,29.172855 -2.281316 0,29.173264 -2.280683 0,29.173674 -2.28005 0,29.174083 -2.279416 0,29.174493 -2.278783 0,29.174902 -2.27815 0,29.175311 -2.277516 0,29.175721 -2.276883 0,29.17613 -2.27625 0,29.17654 -2.275616 0,29.176949 -2.274983 0,29.177358 -2.27435 0,29.177768 -2.273717 0,29.178177 -2.273083 0,29.178586 -2.27245 0,29.178996 -2.271817 0,29.179405 -2.271183 0,29.179815 -2.27055 0,29.180224 -2.269917 0,29.180633 -2.269283 0,29.181043 -2.26865 0,29.181452 -2.268017 0,29.181862 -2.267383 0,29.182271 -2.26675 0,29.18268 -2.266117 0,29.18309 -2.265483 0,29.183499 -2.26485 0,29.183909 -2.264217 0,29.184318 -2.263584 0,29.184727 -2.26295 0,29.185137 -2.262317 0,29.185546 -2.261684 0,29.185956 -2.26105 0,29.186365 -2.260417 0)))

I'm actually trying to isolate various polygons from a collection of about 650, all of which seem to be connected and not their own independent polygon, thus the multipolygon geometry type. When I select one of the polygons and change the geometry type to Polygon Z, this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks all. I actually clipped the first polygon example to make the post smeller but I've updated my post with an unabridged example of one of my polygons. I actually have a .csv file of about 650 polygons which all appear to be connected to each other, thus the multipolygon label. See the edited post for what happens when I try to isolate and include just one of my polygons and change the geometry type to "polygon z"

Answer (score 2):

The WKT you have there is not correct it seems, the syntax is wrong.

You have a space-charakter at the wrong place. For example the -1.778877_0,30.39029 has a space, then a zero then the comma for the next coordinate pair. If this is intended and you want to have the Z-Value you need MultipolygonZ (that is not supported). Also its strange to have a Multipolygon with only one Polygon.

Answer (score 1):

The correct format for your data is not a Multipolygon but a simple Polygon with 3D coordinates

```
'POLYGON Z ((30.389763 -1.778877 0, 30.39029 -1.778926 0, 30.390932 -1.778926 0, 30.391557 -1.778909 0, 30.392068 -1.778876 0, 30.389763 -1.778877 0))'
```

But as all the Z values = 0 you can use

```
'POLYGON ((30.389763 -1.778877, 30.39029 -1.778926, 30.390932 -1.778926, 30.391557 -1.778909, 30.392068 -1.778876, 30.389763 -1.778877))'
```

The Polygon

[image]

A real Multipolygon will be

```
'MULTIPOLYGON (((30.389763 -1.778877, 30.39039977915908 -1.778876723740061, 30.39029 -1.778926, 30.389763 -1.778877)), ((30.39029 -1.778926, 30.39039977915908 -1.778876723740061, 30.39207025070381 -1.7788753753047, 30.39156161728149 -1.778911923814088, 30.39093420120365 -1.778930198068782, 30.39029 -1.778926)))'
```

In red, with 2 polygons

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I put your data in a text file in the format

```
name;WKT
1;MULTIPOLYGON (((29.219629 -2.390692 0,29.219668 -2.391022 0,29.219668 -2.391265 0,29.219563 -2.391476 0,29.21951 -2.391655 0,29.219594 .... )))
```

it displays fine in QGIS, and can be saved as ashapefile. You need to use semicolon as separator of the delimited text.

QGIS reports the geometry type as `Polygon`.